# Execute .cmd file through PowerShell with Runas Different User

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a .cmd file that I need to invoke from a powershell file. But constraint is that I need to execute .cmd file as a different user as well as process should not prompt for authentication. I can provide password with command itself, it is not an issue.

Can someone please help me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use runas

```
runas /savecred /profile /user:<username> <command>
```

It will prompt password first time and save the credential. So from 2nd time onwards, it won't ask for a password.

For eg. if you want to run test.cmd as user varun, then

```
runas /savecred /profile /user:varun test.cmd
```